# OpenCV destroyallWindow function should not work?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg', -1)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
if k == 27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
elif k == ord('s'):
    cv2.imwrite('lena_copy.png', img)
```

I am a beginner in OpenCV. As I was playing around with the functions, I noticed this error. This script, if I understand correctly should first show the image, then will either get destroyed or saved depending on if I press the escape key or s key. But the thing is no matter what key I pressed, the window gets destroyed. It's like I don't need the `destroyAllWindows()` function to destroy all my window, All I need is to press a random key. Is it because I misunderstand the purpose of `destroyAllWindows()` function or is it because of something else?

Answer (score 3):

When you press the escape key, it will explicitly call `destroyAllWindows`. When you press `s`, it will first save the image and then the operating system will destroy all windows upon exit. If you press any other key, again, the OS will close and deallocate all windows upon exit.

From [OpenCV docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#namedwindow):

> You can call `destroyWindow()` or `destroyAllWindows()` to close the
>   window and de-allocate any associated memory usage. For a simple
>   program, you do not really have to call these functions because all
>   the resources and windows of the application are closed automatically
>   by the operating system upon exit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `waitKey` not `destroyAllWindow`. The latter works fine and does what it should do.

You must understand that when you display a window, (by `imshow()`) your application must have main events loop, in which all events related to interactions with the windows like clicking, resizing, moving, displaying etc. are processed. This main loop of GUI application is created and processed in `waitKey()` function invocation.

Your current flow is as follows:

1. show window
2. press any key
3. all windows are closed no matter what key was pressed because you didn't call `waitKey` again for `k == 's'`

.

```
if k == 27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
elif k == ord('s'):
    cv2.imwrite('lena_copy.png', img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

by adding the last line, you start new events loop, and windows are still visible.

Comment: It seems like doing that will only let you run one more time. When you press a random key a third time the image will disappear again. I try to use a while loop but it will only freeze my program